# Get RTF Image Html base64 string as System.Drawing.Image

Tags: c#, system.drawing.imaging

I am storing a Rich Text html string in our database, examples as follows (I have shortened the bit info):

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0...ORK5CYII
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQS...TcUQrQf/Z
```

I need to basically take this HTML and create a `System.Drawing.Image` in C# and then save the image to a location within the Images folder. With the first png example above this all seemed to work fine with the following code:

```
        string imageBase64String = "iVBORw0...ORK5CYII";

        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageBase64String);
        Image image;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        }

        string fileNameFull = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "." + imageFormat;
        string relativePath = @"~\Images\pdfExports\" + fileNameFull;
        string fileLocation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(relativePath);
        image.Save(fileLocation);
```

However when I try other formats including jpg/jpeg it seems like the image is not being created correctly and cannot be read/opened.

Is there a better, more generic way of getting C# `System.Drawing.Image` from this Html String? Or am I just missing something simple with how the base64 string is passed?

**EDIT**
I was late up posting this and missed out some vital info on the code example where I am stripping out the meta data. I have updated now. By the time the string **imageBase64String** is populated I have already stripped out the meta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get this working fine with a simple change. Instead of trying to create a **System.Drawing.Image** object from the byte-array and saving that, i have found using:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(fileLocation, bytes);
```

does the job simply passing the original bytes and a file location. Now I seem to be able to save and open any image format I need.

Answer (score 1):

You are corrupting the image's data, `data:image/png;base64,` is metainformation, not real image content, you must remove that information before converting the data to binary:

```
string imageBase64String = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0...ORK5CYII";

int index = imageBase64String.IndexOf(",");
imageBase64String  = imageBase64String .Substring(index + 1);

byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageBase64String);
```

Comment: Hi Gusman, thanks for the response. I have made an edit on the code above as I have mistakingly shown the wrong string being passed. I have in fact stripped out the meta data from the string - despite what my example previously said. Sorry. As I mentioned, this seems to work fine with PNG files but not jpeg/jpg.